# How do I import qcow2 VM images in ovirt via Admin Portal?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, qemu, linux-kvm

With oVirt node and engine VM installed, I've added my qcow2 image to the export domain (`/nfs/export`). I've tried in both the base dir of export domain, and also in the following (where `/nfs/export/5d1713e7-4299-418a-9768-d5c138357252` is when export domain is loaded into oVirt):

```
/nfs/export/5d1713e7-4299-418a-9768-d5c138357252
/nfs/export/5d1713e7-4299-418a-9768-d5c138357252/images
/nfs/export/5d1713e7-4299-418a-9768-d5c138357252/master
/nfs/export/5d1713e7-4299-418a-9768-d5c138357252/master/vms
```

I don't really see anywhere else that I think would make sense, and none of them resulted in an image showing up when trying to import VM in oVirt Admin Portal from the `export` domain.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you don't need to put the qcow2 image in the export domain.

Instead you can just go to (in Admin Portal):

"Storage" -> "Disks", then in top right press "Upload" and choose "Start" from the drop-down menu. Then you choose the qcow2 file from the location on your local computer, not the machine running oVirt.